# SQL query for generating a full list of Probability outcomes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, union

Let's say that I have a table that looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
    name CHAR NOT NULL,
    Pwin numeric(5,2) NOT NULL 
)

INSERT INTO student 
VALUES ('A', 0.5), 
       ('B', 0.7), 
       ('C', 0.6)
```

This represents 3 students who are competing in separate events. Each of them has a probability of winning their event (Pwin). Those events are independent to each other. The probability of them losing the event is simply = 1 - Pwin.

There are 8 possible outcomes

```
Awin  Bwin  Cwin
Awin  Bwin  Close
Awin  Blose Cwin
Awin  Blose Close
Alose Bwin  Cwin
Alose Bwin  Close
Alose Blose Cwin
Alose Blose Close
```

I want to write a query that will output these probabilities. So for the example above, the output should look like

```
0.5 0.7 0.6
0.5 0.7 0.4
0.5 0.3 0.6
0.5 0.3 0.4
0.5 0.7 0.6
0.5 0.7 0.4
0.5 0.3 0.6
0.5 0.3 0.4
```

Comment: The output you provided is not reflective of the output you asked for.  Any distinct combination of 3 numbers will only give 6 (3 X 2X 1) combinations.  Your query output has duplicates for the first two rows.

Comment: There are more than 3 combinations though since each of the 3 Probabilites can have a Win and Lose value and all need to be accounted for. There happen to be duplicates in the output because I used 0.5 as one of the sample Probabilities and that has the same value for Pwin as Plose but that won't always be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sample data you can get all the possible combinations with as many joins as the number of different names in the table:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT name, Pwin p FROM student
  UNION ALL
  SELECT name, 1 - Pwin FROM student
)
SELECT c1.p col1, c2.p col2, c3.p col3
FROM cte c1 
INNER JOIN cte c2 ON c2.name > c1.name
INNER JOIN cte c3 ON c3.name > c2.name;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1bd013e9effc0270257e9885148b2cee).

Of course this does not scale well, performance wise, for more names.

Comment: That's perfect thanks (very interesting joining technique with the name column)